# Descrição de Arquivos e Diretórios no GitHub

Tags: github, commit

Não consigo inserir uma descrição individualizada em diretórios e arquivos no GitHub.

Em diversos projetos vi este recurso, mas, segundo a documentação, já utilizei o `git add` e posteriormente o `commit -m "descrição"` individualmente, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Você pode ou não criar um arquivo chamado `readme.md` em cada pasta do seu projeto no git 
Nele que você descreve a(as) funcionalidade(s) (Não é obrigatório, caso o repositório não possua o `readme.md` simplesmente ele fica sem nenhuma descrição)

Comment: `commit -m "descrição"` insere a descrição do commit, não do diretórios/repositório

Comment: Olá Marcelo, muito obrigado pela dica, realmente não tinha pensado nessa possibilidade. Sucesso!